# Why does the Mishnah use the terms poor person and homeowner when discussing carrying on Shabbat?

Tags: mishna, maseches-shabbos, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot

This first Mishna in Shabbat ([2a](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.2a.3?lang=bi)) describes the transfer of an item from a private domain to a public domain. The Mishna describes the individuals involved in this transfer as

> העני עומד בחוץ ובעל הבית בפנים
>
> The poor person stands outside, in the public domain, and the homeowner stands inside, in the private domain.

There are many other labels which could have been used including generic names (eg Reuven and Shimon) labels related to the act (machnis/motzi). Why did the Mishna choose to use the specific labels of poor person and homeowner?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Bartenura Shabbat 1:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Bartenura_on_Mishnah_Shabbat.1.1.6?lang=bi):

> ולהכי נקט הוצאה בלשון עני ועשיר, דאגב אורחיה קמ״ל דמצוה הבאה בעבירה אסורה וחייבין עליה:‏
>
> The reason for discussing carrying between domains in the context of a poor and rich person, is to teach something tangential, namely that a *mitzvah* performed via an *aveirah* [i.e. giving charity while carrying on *shabbat*] is forbidden, and one is liable for it.

Comment: The issue with this is that the mishnah starts with a case of the poor person giving something to the rich person.

Comment: @Heshy Yes. He's giving his basket to the rich person, so that the rich person can fill it with food

Comment: Cf. Sukkah 3:14

Comment: As per Joel K's comment above, the idea in the Bartenura of rich person-poor person in the give-take relationship might have something to do with a custom in some households on Shabbos, where Challah is cut, then either placed in a basket or thrown to each person sitting, to symbolize that a) bread comes from heaven and b) the act of handing someone bread is what one does when dealing with a poor person who doesn't have any food.

Comment: Is there a discussion on מצוה הבא בעבירה in the Gemmorah here?

Comment: a similar answer is to teach you that the chiyuv tsedoko is the same as the chiyuv shabbos.

Comment: Another answer to teach you that the 'onee' should wait outside and not go in except on pesach when we invite him in 'kol dichfin 'yeisai' v'yeychol'

Comment: Another answer it is usually an 'onee' who cant wait till baal habayis gives it to him and snatches the food basket   out of his hand.